# Проблема с подключением node-normalize-scss в gulp

Tags: веб-программирование, gulp, gulp-sass

Согласно документации подключаю плагин `npm install node-normalize-scss --save-dev`, в основном sсss-файле делаю импорт `@import "normalize";` затем в компиляции sass в css добавляю строчку кода `includePaths: require("node-normalize-scss").includePaths`. Вылезает ошибка

```
 Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
 Message:
 #src\scss\style.scss
 Error: File to import not found or unreadable: normalize.
    on line 24 of #src/scss/style.scss
      >> @import 'normalize';
```

и файл в директорию не добавляется.

gulpfile.js

```
let { src, dest } = require("gulp");
let gulp = require("gulp");
let scss = require("gulp-sass");
let project_name = require("path").basename(__dirname);
let src_folder = "#src";

let path = {
    build: {
        css: project_name + "/css/",
    },
    src: {
        css: src_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
    }
};

function css() {
    return src(path.src.css, {})
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(
            scss({
                includePaths: require("node-normalize-scss").includePaths,
                outputStyle: "expanded"
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}
Подскажите, что делаю не так
```

Comment: возможно, https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize-scss/issues/109

Comment: не помогло, к сожалению